# I have problems with bean while creating telegram bot using Spring

Tags: java, spring, mysql-workbench, telegram-bot

My bot is about recipes. I have user entity with fields id, userName, firstName, lastName, and registeredAt; user repository that extends from CrudRepository; bot config, which contains fields botName, token and ownerId; bot initializer and service telegram bot.

**BotInitializer**

```
@Slf4j
@Component
public class BotInitializer {
    @Autowired
    TelegramBot tgBot;

    @EventListener({ContextRefreshedEvent.class})
    public void init() throws TelegramApiException {
        TelegramBotsApi telegramBotsApi = new TelegramBotsApi(DefaultBotSession.class);
        try{
            telegramBotsApi.registerBot(tgBot);
        } catch (TelegramApiException e) {
            log.error("Error occurred: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

**service TelegramBot**

```
@Slf4j
@Component
public class TelegramBot extends TelegramLongPollingBot {
    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;
    final BotConfig botConfig;
    static final String HELP_TEXT = "This bot is created to help find recipes for cooking delicious foods.";

    public TelegramBot(BotConfig botConfig, UserRepository userRepository) {
        this.botConfig = botConfig;
        List<BotCommand> commandList = new ArrayList<>();
        commandList.add(new BotCommand("/start", "start communicating with bot"));
        commandList.add(new BotCommand("/help", "help info"));
        commandList.add(new BotCommand("/category", "category of recipes"));
        commandList.add(new BotCommand("/find", "search recipe by name"));
        commandList.add(new BotCommand("/random", "random recipe"));
        try {
            this.execute(new SetMyCommands(commandList, new BotCommandScopeDefault(), null));
        } catch (TelegramApiException e) {
            log.error("Error setting bots command list: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String getBotUsername() {
        return botConfig.getBotName();
    }

    @Override
    public String getBotToken() {
        return botConfig.getToken();
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpdateReceived(Update update) {
        if(update.hasMessage() && update.getMessage().hasText()) {
            String messageText = update.getMessage().getText();
            long chatId = update.getMessage().getChatId();

            switch (messageText) {
                case "/start":
                    registerNewUser(update.getMessage());
                    handleStartCommand(chatId, update.getMessage().getChat().getFirstName());
                    break;
                case "/help" :
                    sendMessage(chatId, HELP_TEXT);
                    break;
                default:
                    sendMessage(chatId, "Command was not recognized");
            }
        }
    }

    private void registerNewUser(Message message) {
        if(userRepository.findById(message.getChatId()).isEmpty()) {
            var chatId = message.getChatId();
            var chat = message.getChat();

            User user = new User();

            user.setChatId(chatId);
            user.setUserName(chat.getUserName());
            user.setFirstName(chat.getFirstName());
            user.setLastName(chat.getLastName());
            user.setRegisteredAt(new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis()));

            userRepository.save(user);
            log.info("User " + user.getUserName() + " is saved");
        }
    }

    public void handleStartCommand(long chatId, String userName) {
        String answer = "Hi, " + userName + " nice to meet you!";
        log.info("Replied to user " + userName + " after getting start command.");
        sendMessage(chatId, answer);
    }

    private void sendMessage(long chatId, String textToSend) {
        SendMessage message = new SendMessage();
        message.setChatId(String.valueOf(chatId));
        message.setText(textToSend);
        try {
            execute(message);
        } catch (TelegramApiException e) {
            log.error("Error occurred: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

**application.properties**

```
bot.name=goldenRecipes
bot.token=Token
bot.owner=OwnerId

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3307/golden-recipes-bot
spring.datasource.username=dbusername
spring.datasource.password=dbpass
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
```

I am trying to connect my bot with mysql database, but i got some errors related to beans and entityManagerFactory.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'botInitializer': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'tgBot'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'telegramBot' defined in file [D:\goldenRecipesBot\target\classes\io\project\goldenRecipesBot\service\TelegramBot.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userRepository' defined in io.project.goldenRecipesBot.repository.UserRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#6bd16207' of type [org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator] while setting bean property 'entityManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#6bd16207': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'entityManagerFactory' available
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:659)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:639)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:119)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1431)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:619)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:955)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:734)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:408)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1306)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1295)
    at io.project.goldenRecipesBot.GoldenRecipesBotApplication.main(GoldenRecipesBotApplication.java:12)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'telegramBot' defined in file [D:\goldenRecipesBot\target\classes\io\project\goldenRecipesBot\service\TelegramBot.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userRepository' defined in io.project.goldenRecipesBot.repository.UserRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#6bd16207' of type [org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator] while setting bean property 'entityManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#6bd16207': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'entityManagerFactory' available
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:800)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:229)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1372)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1391)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1311)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:656)
    ... 19 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userRepository' defined in io.project.goldenRecipesBot.repository.UserRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#6bd16207' of type [org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator] while setting bean property 'entityManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#6bd16207': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'entityManagerFactory' available
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:389)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:134)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1707)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1452)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:619)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1391)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1311)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:887)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:791)
    ... 32 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#6bd16207': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'entityManagerFactory' available
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:342)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:113)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveConstructorArguments(ConstructorResolver.java:693)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:510)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1352)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1195)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:374)
    ... 46 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'entityManagerFactory' available
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:874)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getMergedLocalBeanDefinition(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1344)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:309)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:330)
    ... 54 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm working on a similar project and had exactly the same issue. Spent plenty of time until figured out that it comes from pom.xml file. I just deleted all versions from the dependencies and reloaded it, seems to me that the problem is that some of the libraries were not loaded properly or the versions were incompatible. Let me know if it works for you.

Here is my example:

```
 <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.telegram</groupId>
        <artifactId>telegrambots</artifactId>
        <version>${telegram.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>appassembler-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <assembleDirectory>target</assembleDirectory>
                <programs>
                    <program>
                        <mainClass>com.telegarambot.customertgbot.CustomerTgBotApplication</mainClass>
                        <name>workerBot</name>
                    </program>
                </programs>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>assemble</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```